# Proof using the definition of limit that $\lim _{(x,y)\to(0,1)}\frac{x^2-y^2}{x^2+y^2} = -1$

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

Proof using the definition of limit that

## $$\lim _{(x,y)\to(0,1)}\frac{x^2-y^2}{x^2+y^2} = -1$$

and

## $$\lim_{ (x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{ (1-\cos(xy))\sin y}{(x^2+y^2) }= 0$$

> **Definition of limit:**
>
> $\lim_{(x,y)\to(a,b)} f(x,y) =L$ if and only if for every $\epsilon >0$ exist $\delta>0$ such that if $\sqrt{(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2}<\delta$ then $|f(x,y)-L|<\epsilon$.

Comment: What've you tried?

Answer (score 1):

For the first one: For $\epsilon > 0$ given, let $\delta = \min\left(\dfrac{1}{2}, \sqrt{\dfrac{\epsilon}{8}}\right) \to 1-|y| = |1| - |y| \leq |y-1| \leq \sqrt{x^2+(y-1)^2} < \delta < \dfrac{1}{2} \to |y| > \dfrac{1}{2} \to \left|\dfrac{x^2-y^2}{x^2+y^2}-(-1)\right| = \dfrac{2x^2}{x^2+y^2} < \dfrac{2x^2}{\left(\dfrac{1}{2}\right)^2} = 8x^2 < 8\cdot \left(\sqrt{\dfrac{\epsilon}{8}}\right)^2 = \epsilon$. You can do the other one similarly by finding the right bounds.

For the second one, you should use the followings in your answer:

$1)$. $x^2+y^2 \geq 2|xy|$

$2)$. $\left|\dfrac{\sin^2(xy)}{(xy)^2}-1\right| < \dfrac{1}{2} \to \sin^2(xy) < 2(xy)^2$ for $|xy|$ is small enough

$3)$. $ 1- \cos(xy) = 2\sin^2\left(\dfrac{xy}{2}\right)$

$4)$. $|\sin(y)| \leq 1$.

Comment: thanks, i am novate, i don know why $\delta = \min\left(\dfrac{1}{2},\sqrt{\dfrac{\epsilon}{8}}\right)$